# Why is Toradol no longer available in the US?

Tags: medications, nsaids-pain-meds, analgesics

A few years ago I was given Toradol for kidney stone pain. It was magical. My friend just had a kidney stone and was given morphine, then Dilaudid. Curious about the differences, I went googling, only to learn that Toradol is no longer [available](https://www.rxlist.com/toradol_vs_dilaudid/drugs-condition.htm) in the US.

I couldn’t find any more information about when or why this occurred, even on the Roche [website](https://www.roche.com/products/product-details.htm?productId=eb40c4bd-77ca-4ff2-bf38-93dad2fdad65).

Why is Toradol no longer available in the US, and when did this occur?

Comment: It's only the brand name Toradol that's unavailable. The drug itself is still used. In 2016 over a million prescriptions for ketorolac (the generic name) were prescribed in the US. So Toradol being taken off the market was a corporate decision made for reasons we can probably never know.

Answer (score -3):

Toradol is the brand name that has been discontinued by the FDA; however, the generic name Ketorolac is still in use in the USA.

Here is the reason why the FDA discontinued Toradol:
In 2020, it was the 249th most commonly prescribed medication in the United States, with more than 1 million prescriptions.
Due to a series of deaths due to gastrointestinal bleeding and kidney failure, Ketorolac as a pain medication was removed from the German market in 1993.
When Ketorolac was introduced into Germany, it was often misused as an opioid replacement in pain therapy because its side effects were perceived as much less severe, it did not produce any dependence, and a dose was effective for 7–8 hours compared to morphine with 3–4 hours. As a very potent prostaglandin inhibitor,
ketorolac diminishes the kidney's defenses against vasoconstriction-related effects, e.g. during blood loss or high endogenous catecholamine levels.
If you research the side effects of Toradol, which are the same as Ketorolac, you will see that it is a super dangerous drug reason as this is why it was discontinued in the USsA.

Comment: Why would the FDA pull the brand name from the market but not the generic? If the reason was that it was deemed too dangerous, they would have pulled the generic as well.